# How to get all child of a parent and their children using recursion

Tags: java

[refference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275833/how-to-get-all-children-of-a-parent-and-then-their-children-using-recursion)

Here I want to get all the children of a parent.
This is my [Screen.](https://plnkr.co/edit/XgfuZho0E8Gi5d1CbOrH?p=preview)

In This screen I want to save all the rows. For that I have created the following beans.

```
public class AdminComponentBean{

    List<MultiAdminComponent> componentListbean;
}
```

**Another Bean:-**

```
public class MultiAdminComponent {

    private String componentName;
    private String componentIdentification;
    private String componentType;
    private String componentState;
    private String componentUrl;
    private String rowId;
    private List<MultiAdminComponent> items;
    }
```

In my service I try to retrieve all the children. But I am not able to get children of the parent.

```
  List < MultiAdminComponent > adminComponentList = adminComponentBean.getComponentListbean();
       for (MultiAdminComponent adminComponentListBean: adminComponentList) {

          flag = BaseDAO.getAdminComponentDAOObject().saveParentComponentDetails(adminComponentListBean);//Here the parents will save but not the childs
          for (MultiAdminComponent adminComponentchild: adminComponentListBean.getItems()) {//here I am trying to save childs

          }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a recursive method like this:

```
void addChildren(MultiAdminComponent parent, List<MultiAdminComponent> children) {
    if(null != parent.getItems()) {
        for(MultiAdminComponent child : parent.getItems()) {
            children.add(child);
            addChildren(child, children);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it with an empty list, e.g.:

```
MultiAdminComponent parent; //parent
List<MultiAdminComponent> children = new ArrayList<>();
addChildren(parent, children);
```

After the method call, `children` list should have all the child objects.

Comment: The above code is working fine and when getting data also do we need to write the same kind of recursive method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629162/how-to-get-parent-and-child-records-with-recursive-method

Comment: You can call the same method to get the data

Comment: I can't able to use the same method as while getting the records there will be no relation as child and parent relationship.. I will get individual records

Comment: If I use the same Method then that Object should contain childs so it will give all the childs of the parent

Comment: But I want to set the childs to parent