# How to write a recursive method for finding parent and child

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json, spring

[This is to save the details with recursive.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611663/how-to-get-all-child-of-a-parent-and-their-children-using-recursion/45612226#45612226)

Here I want to get the details from the Database and set into my bean with a recursive method. So I can dispaly in angularUi tree formate. How can I write the recursive method to set into my beans.

**My DB Stricture:-**
[image]

I am separating the parents and childs with rowId.you can access my sample [screen](https://plnkr.co/edit/dlG6bJcBP8jaxhVEZ4wq?p=preview).

Eg:- Rowid is 1 for parent
   the child for this 1 is 1.1
and child for 1.1 is 1.1.1 like this it will prolong,,.

I am saving all the parents and child in a single table which is above image.

there will be `items[]` for each and every object(Row). If there is any child for parent then the child will be added in that `items[]` array, if that child have any child then the child will be added in the parent of that row's `items[]`... like this it will prolong.

**Eg:- JSON object is:-**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "rowId": "1",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "rowId": "1.1",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 100,
            "rowId": "1.1.1",
            "items": [
              {
                "id": 1000,
                "rowId": "1.1.1.1",
                "items": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "rowId": "1.2",
        "items": []
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have saved this data using the [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611663/how-to-get-all-child-of-a-parent-and-their-children-using-recursion/45612226#45612226)

But while retriving I am facing problems. The problem is while retrieving there will not be any parent and childs as the data will be saved in same table.The relationship is only rowid. For This I need to write a recursive method like saving, and need to add the childs to parent `items[]` array.

```
public class AdminComponentBean{

    List<MultiAdminComponent> componentListbean;
}
```

**MultiAdminComponent.java:-**

```
public class MultiAdminComponent {

    private String componentName;
    private String componentIdentification;
    private String componentType;
    private String componentState;
    private String componentUrl;
    private String rowId;
    private List<MultiAdminComponent> items;
}
```

Here I try to retrive all the details and trying to add the childs to parent.But it should make a recursive method

```
List<MultiAdminComponent> componentList=BaseDAO.getAdminComponentDAOObject().getComponentDetails();
   if(null != componentList) {
       for(MultiAdminComponent itemsList : componentList){
           if(itemsList.getRowId().length().equals() "1"){//here parent row will come
               //by considering rowid I need to find the child of the rowId
               //child of 1 is 1.1
               //if 1.1 is child of 1 then I need to add that 1.1 object to `items[]` array of 1
               //like this it should work recursve
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have a parent id (assumign that's what "rowId" means) that should be fairly simple (higher performance would probably make it more complex so we'll stick with simple for now): 1) get all elements that have no parent 2) until you don't get any more data do the following: a) get all elements whose rowId matches one of the ids of the elements last loaded and b) attach the loaded elements to their parents by using the rowId for the mapping. When you don't get any more elements you're done.

Comment: rowid is unique for each and every row

Comment: @Thomas can you please give some more clarity

Comment: Actually, have a look at Absurd-Mind's answer which seems to make use of the fact that "rowId" basically contains the index of all parents on their respective levels (and thus `rowId = parent.rowId + indexInParent`). Hence you can load partial trees in one query (e.g. `... where rowId in ('1','1.1') or rowId like '1.1.%'` to get elements 1, 1.1 and all children of 1.1) and, as Absurd-Mind suggested , use a map to connect the loaded elements to one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of recursive I would suggest to go an extra step and store all elements in a HashMap

```
// a map containing all elements searchable by the rowId
HashMap<String, MultiAdminComponent> idToItem = new HashMap<>();
// a set containing all elements that don't have a parent (id: 1, 2, 3, etc.)
Set<MultiAdminComponent> rootItems = new HashSet<>();

for (MultiAdminComponent item : componentList) {
    // build the id->item map
    idToItem.put(item.getRowId(), item);
}

for (MultiAdminComponent item : componentList) {
    String parentId = getParentId(item.getRowId());
    if (parentId == null) {
        // this item has no parent -> it is a root item
        rootItems.add(item);
    } else {
        // This item has a parent -> look the parent up
        MultiAdminComponent parent = idToItem.get(parentId);
        parent.getItems().add(item);
    }
}

// rootItems now contains all MultiAdminComponents which do not have a parent, with the correct hierarchy for all items
```

getParentId could be something like this:

```
private String getParentId(String id) {
    int lastDot = id.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (lastDot == -1) {
        return null;
    }
    return id.substring(0, lastDot);
}
```

If you can guarantee that componentList will go through the list from parents to children, you can combine both for-loops.