# substring is not working

Tags: java, string

[This is my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633934/how-to-write-a-recursive-method-for-finding-parent-and-child)

In my above question's answer `return id.substring(0, lastDot - 1);` in this line `lastDot` is getting problem.

If I have the id 1.1 the in the above line `lastDot` value is `1` the substring is getting `""`.

How can I avoid the problem.

```
private String getParentId(String id) {
    int lastDot = id.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (lastDot == -1) {
        return null;
    }
    return id.substring(0, lastDot - 1);
}
```

Comment: Read the docs for substring.  If you pay attention, you'll see your misunderstanding.  Don't subtract.  It would have been faster to read the docs and experiment with your code than ask on SO.  It's already been 16 minutes since you asked.  This would have been easy to fix with a minute or two in a debugger.  Every problem is not a good candidate for asking here.

Comment: In your example, 
substring appears to be the wrong method.

Consider using split and split on '.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

The second parameter is the length of the string starting from the first parameter, so if you are always starting with index 0 , you do not need to subtract 1

```
return id.substring(0, lastDot);
```

A more general approach would be to always subtract the first parameter

```
  int offset = 0;
return id.substring(offset, lastDot-offset);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 return id.substring(0, lastDot);
```

is what you meant probably. But think of the case when your id would be `1.2.3` what would like to return in this case? `1.2` or `2` or `1`.  At the moment your function will return `1.2` at it might be correct - but that depends on your needs.